# Why python not returning it's value in double quotes when it is string

Tags: python, string, integer

I have converted integer value to string although it is not returning in quotes ad strings does

[cmd ][1]

> > > print(str(31))
> > > 31 #I think it should give result as "31" because now it is string

Comment: Because while returning it prints the value, the double quotes are not printed. Though it will be treated as a string, you can verify it by using concatenation through `+` or string multiplication as `str(32)*3` this will give you `323232`

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

When string is printed, quotes are usually not added. If you wanna see quote then use the repr() function. For example,

```
print(repr("31"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because while returning it prints the value, the double quotes are not printed. Though it will be treated as a string, you can verify it by using concatenation through `+` or string multiplication as `str(32)*3` this will give you `323232`